# 'Application' failed to launch in time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, xcode5

The app I'm currently working on has a very strange behaviour. Whenever I install a test build through XCode, iTunes or TestFlightApp the application starts normally and runs very well. The 
 problem comes when I manually kill the app and start it again. Then the launch image is displayed and that's the furthest the app goes - it just freezes for some time and the OS wipes out the whole process after that. The crash log contain rather not useful information as it states - **Application Specific Information:  failed to launch in time**.
Also the console in organizer logs the following:

- Notice: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'
- Warning: com.*.* failed to launch in time
- Warning: Forcing crash report of MyApp[7956]...
- Warning: Finished crash reporting.
- Notice: (UIKitApplication:com.*.*[0x6a86]) Exited: Killed: 9
- Notice: (UIKitApplication:com.*.*[0x6a86]) Throttling respawn: Will
  start in 2147483625 seconds
- Warning: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.*.*[0x6a86]' exited
  abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

I've already spent a whole day in researching the question. Just to clarify - Any synchronous work or any large amount of work is not performed on any of the UIApplication delegate methods 
(applicationDidBecomeActive, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, etc.).
What I noticed is if any URL requests aren't performed during the execution the problem simply doesn't occur that is the app runs normally the second time after being killed before that.
Just to mention that the problem occurs under iOS 7 but the app supports iOS 5 and 6 too.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){if (nil == error) {                                
                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
                                      (...)//creating ppError
                                       if (nil == ppError) {
                                           result = parsing(json, &ppError);

                                           if (nil != ppError) {
                                               result = nil;
                                           }
                                       }
                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                                           if (PPServiceReturnedInvalidTokenErrorCode == ppError.code) {
                                            (...)//do some parsing stuff

                                               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:PPRequestManagerUserAuthenticationTokenDidExprireNotification
                                                                                                   object:self
                                                                                                 userInfo:userInfo];
                                           }
                                           completion(result, ppError);
                                       });
                                   });
                               }
                               else {
                                   completion(nil, ppError);
                               }
                           }];
```

That's basically how all requests are being made so I think that everything is correct and yet it's a fact that if I comment this code the described problem simply disappears.

Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use instruments to see what the app does and where in your code it is consuming that much time. Usually this happens if the main thread is blocked and the app taking more than around 10 seconds on startup to get responsive.

Comment: in your completion handler, the second dispatch_async(), did you mean to dispatch to the current queue? because that won't do anything, you're by definition already on the current queue

Comment: @PatrickGoley `dispatch_async` on the current queue shuffles the code to at least the next runloop. So it does "something". One of the side-effects of this shuffle is the current runloop finishes and tells SpringBoard that the app has launched in time.

Comment: The crash log should show a stack trace of what's happening at the time you are removed from memory, in particular the trace of the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to resolve the issue - The problem was a third party framework for establishment of HTTP connections which was part of the project though not used. It was starting its own thread and executing a task which eventually resulted in crash sometimes.

It was tricky to conclude what was causing the crash but the Organizer on Xcode 5 did a great job. I used the symbolicated crash logs there which the connected device was generating and luckily the stack trace revealed the secret.

I was thinking that incorrect build configuration was the reason or bug in the OS even.  Anyway, thank you for the help! I'd be glad to help too if someone out there has similar problems.